# has no setter to the method saveformat

Tags: flutter, dart, aspose.words

Trying to use [aspose_words_cloud](https://pub.dev/packages/aspose_words_cloud) package in flutter. The class `SaveOptionsData`
that is a method from class called Api , the purpose from it is to convert  docx to pdf , when I call `saveFormat` from the class `SaveOptionsData` gives me the error

> here isn’t a setter named 'saveFormat' in class 'SaveOptionsData'

```dart
var wordsApi = WordsApi(configuration);
var pdfSaveOptions = SaveOptionsData();
pdfSaveOptions.fileName = 'dest.pdf';
// the error  appears here 
pdfSaveOptions.saveFormat= "pdf";
var saveAsRequest = SaveAsRequest('source.docx', pdfSaveOptions);
wordsApi.saveAs(saveAsRequest);
```

the code in reference in the `SaveOptionsData` class, which was ABSTRACT BEFORE I

```
//CHANGE IT  
String _saveFormat; 
String get saveFormat => _saveFormat;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`aspose_words_cloud`](https://pub.dev/packages/aspose_words_cloud) provides `PdfSaveOptionsData()` for pdf.

```dart
var pdfSaveOptions = PdfSaveOptionsData();
```

Also you can also create another class extending `SaveOptionsData` and use it as `PdfSaveOptionsData`.

```dart
class CustomOption extends SaveOptionsData {
....
}

///use case
var pdfSaveOptions = CustomOption();
```

Comment: this was useful thanks